# Make module available via AMD, bower, simple browser JS, and node

Tags: javascript, node.js, amd, commonjs

I just wrote a module ( https://github.com/mercmobily/simpleDeclare ) and made it available as a Node module via NPM. It follows CommonJS.

I would like to make it also available to people using Bower, and AMD-like loader, and a straight include using the browser.

What's the current pattern to make this happen? Or, is it even possible? I *remember* seeing a few modules that did it, but cannot find them and am only finding outdated and not-so-definite information (but I suspect I am looking for the wrong thing).

Comment: I think this is called UMD (Universal Module Definition). Read this: http://bob.yexley.net/umd-javascript-that-runs-anywhere/, it should help you. Check also: https://github.com/umdjs/umd

Comment: Maybe this is the current answer? http://know.cujojs.com/tutorials/modules/authoring-umd-modules